# Recording incoming and outgoing calls with BR using Telephony Manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediarecorder

I'm writing an app that is supposed to detect incoming/outgoing calls and record them. 
I've managed to get the broadcast receiver to register and start recording the call but i cant get it to stop.

Attached is the code of the relevant BroadcastReciever I wrote , and BTW it's being called from a service.

```
public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)){
        String incnum = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int day = new Date().getDate(), mont = new Date().getMonth() , yea = new Date().getYear(), hou = new Date().getHours(), min = new Date().getMinutes();
        String s = ""+day+"_"+mont+"_"+yea+"_"+hou+"_"+min+"_"+incnum+"_Incoming"+".3gp";
         final AudioRecorder ar = new AudioRecorder(s, context);
         ar.start();
         Thread th = new Thread(){
             public void run(){
                 String stat = TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED;
                while(stat == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                    stat = TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED;
                }
                ar.stop();
             }
         };
         th.start();
    }



}
```

Please advise , i couldnt find any details about a similar problem on the web :\

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BroadcastReceiver reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

The story is: BroadcastReceiver when fired lives only for 10 seconds, after it's get killed by OS if it still didn't return from onReceive() method.
Start a service after you got a call and record there then stop this service from another receiver when phone state changed.